# Using NetBeans 8 but getting below compilation error for Lambda expression

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, netbeans-8

I am using NetBeans 8. When my code contains a Lambda expression and I try to compile, I get the following error message:

```
lambda expression not expected here

lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

Comment: You need to tell netbeans you are using java 8 in your project's properties.

Comment: Yes I have selected Java Platform as JDK 1.8 Default but Still getting this Error.

Comment: Are you using *-source 1.5*? Then it will, as the error message indicates, indeed not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change compiler version of your source code into your project properties to jdk 8 and firstly check whether you have installed one.

Comment: Thanks. Your right, In Net Beans I am using 8 only but by default Compiler or Source/Binary format was 1.5 only.
Now i have changed to 1.8, It's working now

Comment: @Pushkar can you explain where you changed this?

Comment: @tier1 In menu follow path
Menu >> Properties >> Java Compiler

here I have made changes.

Answer (score 26):

Please click right from you project -> Properties -> Choose Sources -> (you will see Source/Binary Format) change it to 1.8 -> Click OK.

Or you can see in this link http://tinadev.blogspot.com/2015/08/lambda-expression-not-expected-here.html

Thanks

[image: For NetBeans IDE 8.2, JDK 8]

Answer (score 4):

In the project properties dialog, select Sources in the left panel and then on the bottom right look for "Source/Binary Format"  Change that to JDK 8.

Comment: And also in the Libraries category, Make certain "Java Platform" is also JDK 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Download JDK 1.8 to resolve this issue.
change the JAVA_HOME environment variables path to jdk_1.8.
Right Click on the project folder which has the above mentioned compilation error and select properties. 
In Sources tab change the source/binary format to JDK 8.
In libraries change Java Platform to JDK 1.8.